# Trouble with MVC Navbar Home button Get Request

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net-core-mvc

I am having this issue with my home button not adding headers in a get request. I have stored a token inside of the localStorage and I send it in the headers when I make a get request to Controller: Home Action: Index. From what I see, it doesn't use my jquery and goes straight to the Account/Index.

Below is my code for the file "Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml":

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>@ViewData["Title"] - Chat</title>

        <environment include="Development">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
        </environment>
        <environment exclude="Development">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
                  asp-fallback-href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
                  asp-fallback-test-class="sr-only" asp-fallback-test-property="position" asp-fallback-test-value="absolute" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.min.css" asp-append-version="true" />
        </environment>
        <script src="~/js/NavBarFunctions.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li id="li_btnHome"><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">A Different Page</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <div class="container body-content">
            @RenderBody()
            <hr />
            <footer>
                <p>&copy; 2018 - Chat</p>
            </footer>
        </div>

        <environment include="Development">
            <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
            <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
            <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
        </environment>
        <environment exclude="Development">
            <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
                    asp-fallback-src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
                    asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery"
                    crossorigin="anonymous"
                    integrity="sha384-tsQFqpEReu7ZLhBV2VZlAu7zcOV+rXbYlF2cqB8txI/8aZajjp4Bqd+V6D5IgvKT">
            </script>
            <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.7/bootstrap.min.js"
                    asp-fallback-src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
                    asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery && window.jQuery.fn && window.jQuery.fn.modal"
                    crossorigin="anonymous"
                    integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa">
            </script>
            <script src="~/js/site.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
        </environment>

        @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
    </body>
</html>
```

Here's the javascript file "wwwroot/js/NavBarFunctions.js":

```js
    $("#li_btnHome a")[0].click(function (event) {
        alert("Called click")
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8;',
            url: '@Url.Action("Index", "Home")',
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", localStorage.getItem("token"));
            },
            success: function (response) {
                $("html").html(response);
            }
        });
    });
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Chat.Enums;
using Chat.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;

namespace _Chat.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private AuthenticateUser authenticateUser = new AuthenticateUser();

        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            var request = Request;
            var headers = request.Headers;

            StringValues token;
            if (headers.TryGetValue("Authorization", out token))
            {
                var result = await this.authenticateUser.ValidateToken(token);
                if (result.Result == AuthenticateResult.Success)
                {
                    return View();
                }
                else
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Account");
                }
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Account");
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** For some odd reason, it looks like after my page is redirected from log in to home, all scripts/javascript stop working.

Here's the code authenticating login. Located in "Controllers/AccountController":

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Chat.Models;
using Chat.DatabaseAccessObject;
using Chat.Identity;
using Chat.DatabaseAccessObject.CommandObjects;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Net.Mime;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;

namespace Chat.Controllers
{
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        private const string SECRET_KEY = "CHATSECRETKEY";
        public static SymmetricSecurityKey SIGNING_KEY = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(SECRET_KEY));
        private ServerToStorageFacade serverToStorageFacade = new ServerToStorageFacade();
        private AuthenticateUser authenticateUser = new AuthenticateUser();

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // Post: /login/
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody]LoginModel loginModel)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var mapLoginModelToUser = new MapLoginModelToUser();
                var user = await mapLoginModelToUser.MapObject(loginModel);

                // If login user with those credentials does not exist
                if(user == null)
                {
                    return BadRequest();
                }

                else
                {
                    var result = await this.authenticateUser.Authenticate(user);

                    if(result.Result == Chat.Enums.AuthenticateResult.Success)
                    {
                        // SUCCESSFUL LOGIN
                        // Creating and storing cookies

                        var token = Json(new
                        {
                            data = this.GenerateToken(user.Email, user.PantherID),
                            redirectUrl = Url.Action("Index","Home"),
                            success = true
                        });
                        return Ok(token);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Unsuccessful login
                        return Unauthorized();
                    }
                }
            }

            return BadRequest();
        }

        private string GenerateToken(string email, string pantherId)
        {
            var claimsData = new[] { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, email), new Claim(ClaimTypes.Actor, pantherId) };

            var signInCredentials = new SigningCredentials(SIGNING_KEY, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
            var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                issuer: "localhost",
                audience: "localhost",
                expires: DateTime.Now.AddDays(7),
                claims: claimsData,
                signingCredentials: signInCredentials
            );

            return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
        }

        [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Error() => View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
    }

    public class MapLoginModelToUser
    {
        private ServerToStorageFacade serverToStorageFacade;

        public MapLoginModelToUser()
        {
            serverToStorageFacade = new ServerToStorageFacade();
        }


        public async Task<User> MapObject(LoginModel loginModel)
        {
            Expression<Func<User, bool>> expression = x => x.Email == loginModel.inputEmail;

            var user = await this.serverToStorageFacade.ReadObjectByExpression(new User(Guid.NewGuid()), expression);

            if(user == default(Command))
            {
                return null;
            }

            return new User(user.ID)
            {
                Email = loginModel.inputEmail,
                Password = loginModel.inputPassword,
                FirstName = user.FirstName,
                LastName = user.LastName,
                PantherID = user.PantherID,
                ClassDictionary = user.ClassDictionary,
                UserEntitlement = user.UserEntitlement
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Also the code that renders the page. Located in "wwwroot/js/Login.js":

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#formSubmit").submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var email = $("#inputEmail").val();
        var password = $("#inputPassword").val();
        var remember = $("#rememberMe").val();
        var loginModel = {
            inputEmail: email,
            inputPassword: password,
            rememberMe: remember
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'Account/Login',
            data: JSON.stringify(loginModel),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8;',
            success: function (response) {
                var token = response.value.data;
                localStorage.setItem("token", token);
                alert("You have successfully logged in.");
                setHeader();
                redirect(response.value.redirectUrl);
            }
        });
    });

    function setHeader() {
        $.ajaxSetup({
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', localStorage.getItem("token"));
            }
        });
    }

    function redirect(redirectUrl) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8;',
            url: redirectUrl,
            success: function (response) {
                $("html").html(response);
            }
        });    
    }
});
```

I just noticed there is something off when none of the scripts (or any javascript for that matter) works. I believe it may be triggered with the line `$("html").html(response);`. AccountController/Login Returns a view, and this was the only way I knew of displaying a view.

This is the error received after loading the new html page:
[image: Console Redirect Error]

Comment: Will it work if you add the following property to your ajax request? `headers: { "Authorization":  localStorage.getItem("token").toString(); }`. This is how I normally add / modify the request header.

Comment: Yes this works, what doesn't work is the click function specified in NavBarFunctions.js when I click on the `<li id="li_btnHome"><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">A Different Page</a></li>`

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with the location of NavBarFunctions.js in your layout. You're loading the JS and trying to bind the click event before the li_btnHome element has been created. You're also trying to do this before JQuery has been loaded on the page.

Take the script out of the page header and move it down the bottom, near the RenderSection for the scripts.

Comment: I moved the NavBarFunction Script directly above the RenderSection and it doesn't work. I am not getting the alert when it's clicked.

Answer (score 1):

The way you bind `click` handler with `jQuery` is not correct :

```
$("#li_btnHome a")[0].click(function(event){
    // ...
})
```

`$(selector)` will return a collection of matched elements . **However ,`$(selector)[0]` is  not a jQuery object , but a normal DOM element** . **So you cannot bind `onclick` event handler by using `.click(function(event){/* ... */})`** .

Also ,

1. It's good to `return false;`
2. As @[I. R. R](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5330050/i-r-r) said , you should convert the token to string .
3. As @[Lyons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52656755/10091607) said , you should make the code executed after the jQuery loaded

To bind the onclick handler correctly , change your code as below  :

```
$("#li_btnHome a")[0].onclick=function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("called click");
    var tokenObj = localStorage.getItem("token");
    var tokenStr = tokenObj==null ? "what_about_tokenObj_is_null?": tokenObj.toString();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8;',
        url: '@Url.Action("Index", "Home")',
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization",tokenStr);
        },
        success: function (response) {
            alert(1);
            $("html").html(response);
        }
    });
    return false;
};
```

Comment: I did this, and it still doesn't use the click event. I'm not getting any alerts. It redirects me to the Home/Index with the asp-controller and asp-action belonging to the anchor tag. I copied your code into my script directly above the render scripts section.

Comment: @OneEyedTurkey It works flawlessly on my PC. It's strange that it doesn't works for you. I'm wondering whether there's some other error in those code that you didn't mention here . Could you please press `F12` to see if there's something strange , such as the script is not loaded , or there're other error before this script is executed ? Or if possible, could yo please upload the complete project to GitHub ?

Comment: When I check the console from Chrome, it does not indicate that there were any errors.